# xmllint displays value of second attribute if first one matches

Tags: xmllint

my xml looks like

```
<list1>
   <list2 id="abc" value="yes"></list2>
   <list2 id="xyz" value="no"></list2>
   <list2 id="def" value="yes"></list2>
<list1>
```

using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) but I am not able to get the right output. When I query the above xml giving "abc", I need "yes" returned.

Comment: What XPath query are you using?

Comment: now I am trying to use xmllint //list1/list2[@id="abc"]/@value' | xmllint --shell myxml | awk -F'[="]' '!/>/{print $(NF-1)}'  when I run on console it works but unable to capture it to a var.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XPath `string()` function to get just the value of the `value` attribute:

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'string(//list1/list2[@id="abc"]/@value)' data.xml
yes
```

You would capture this to a variable using typical `bash` syntax:

```
value=$(
  xmllint --xpath \
  'string(//list1/list2[@id="abc"]/@value)' data.xml
)
```

And then:

```
echo $value
```

Results in:

```
yes
```

Comment: If your `xmllint` doesn't have the `xpath` option, use whatever syntax you have been using for doing XPath queries.  This works on all of the systems to which I have access, but you may have an older version of `xmllint`.

Comment: echo 'cat //list1/list2[@id="abc"]/@value' | xmllint --shell myxml | awk -F'[="]' '!/>/{print $(NF-1)}'   works fine from console but fails when used in the script.  when executed the script it gives: cat //list1/list2[@id="abc"]/@value No such file or directory

Comment: @kumar2008 While I agree that you should continue whatever methods you have been using, I urge you to try to upgrade `xmllint`, usually part of your distribution's `libxml2` package.  Using `sed` and `awk` are your next choice, but the Xpaths get tougher and harder to debug.

Comment: eyoung, as we don't have xmllint. any option of using sed? any help on that command would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `xml` is in incorrect format. You have a premature end of data in tag list1. Should have `</list1>` at the end.
2. As @eyoung100 suggested, please upgrade your `xmllint`.
3. `echo 'cat //list1/list2[@id="abc"]/@value' | xmllint --shell myxml | awk -F'[="]' '!/>/{print $(NF-1)}'` will work if you correct the `xml` as mentioned in point 1 & make sure you have the `myxml` file in your current working directory(or use absolute paths), though it's not the right way of doing things.

Code:

```
myvar='abc'
myxml='myxml'
myvalue="cat //list1/list2[@id=\"'$myvar'\"]/@value | xmllint --shell $myxml"
sh -c "echo $myvalue | gawk -F'[=\"]' '!/>/{print \$(NF-1)}'"
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Whoot!!!! Someone finally agrees with me :)

Comment: sorry my bad. xml in file is correct format but while pasting missed it. I have challenge to get the value into variable.

Comment: Neuron, it is working from command prompt as expected. When I include this in the script. in the script Instead of "abc" hardcoded the value comes as variable ($myvar), instead of echo I have to save the output of @value to my value variable and myxml comes as variable $myxml aswell. I am using below command in script:

myvalue= `cat //list1/list2[@id="'$myvar'"]/@value | xmllint --shell $myxml | awk -F'[="]' '!/>/{print $(NF-1)}'`

failing with error: cat: //list1/list2[@id="$myvar"]/@value: No such file or directory

Comment: @kumar2008: please see the edited post. I have pasted the script there

Comment: Hi Neuron and others, 

The above xmllint doesn't execute from AIX. It works fine with Linux. Any help?  any command using sed?